# Узнать количество недель в году

Tags: дата, веб-программирование, php

Здравствуйте!

Помогите узнать количество недель в году, используя php.

Comment: 52 (пятьдесят две)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$year='2014';//год
echo date('W',mktime(0,0,0,12,31,$year));
```

Пишем велик

```
function getCountWeek($year)
{
    $date=date('w',mktime(0,0,0,12,31,$year));
    $day=($date<4?31-$date:31);
    return date('W',mktime(0,0,0,12,$day,$year))+($date<4?1:0);    
}
```

**Обновление**

Кому интересно. По ISO 8601 первая неделя не та, что начинается с первого января, а та, что содержит первый четверг года.
Сам в шоке)

Comment: Забавно, но почему-то некорректно отрабатывает на некоторых годах

`
2014: 01
2015: 53
2016: 52
2017: 52
2018: 01
2019: 01
2020: 53
2021: 52
2022: 52
2023: 52
2024: 01
2025: 01
2026: 53
2027: 52
2028: 52
2029: 01
`

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @Ale_x, Ваш вариант почему-то показывал неверный результат. Немного переделал:

    function get_weeks_in_year($year) {

        $year--;

        $date = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, $year));

        $day = ($date < 4 ? 31 - $date : 31);

        return date('W', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, $day, $year));
    }